# How do I sync a video with its transcript in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, srt, transcription

I am using Next.js and a transcription API for a project. I have a video file and I would like to display a transcript next to it. The transcript can be obtained in JSON, VTT, SRT, or DPE formats. I want to achieve the following functionality:

As the user scrubs through the video, the pointer should move accordingly throughout the transcript.
When the user clicks on a specific part of the transcript, the video should jump to that timestamp.
Additionally, the user should be able to rename speakers.
How can I implement this in a Next.js application?

Thank you in advance.